# Transform single row into rows and columns

Tags: r

I have a list of 170 items, each with 12 variables. This data is currently organised in one continuous row (1 observations of 2040 variables), e.g.:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

but I want it to be organised into 170 columns with 12 rows as follows:

```
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

I have tried the following:

```
list2=lapply(list1, function(x) t(x))
```

but this doesn't alter the data in any way. Is there something else I can do to transform the data?

Comment: Is it a string or a vector of numeric elements?

Comment: If it's just numeric values you could do something like `matrix(as.vector(list1),ncol=170)`

Comment: It's a string of numerical elements

Comment: Do you assume that each group of 12 values has the same value (0, 1, 2 etc.) as you show it in the example data?

Answer (score 2):

We convert the string to a `vector` of numeric elements with `scan`, `split` the `vector` by itself to create a `list` and convert it to a `data.frame`

```
v2 <- scan(text=v1, what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
data.frame(split(v2, v2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is already converted into a vector (as @akrun showed with using `scan`) you could also do:

```
data <- 1:2040  # your data
breaks <- seq(1, 2040, 170)
result <- lapply(breaks, function(x) data[x : (x + 169)])
```

Results in

```
> str(result)
List of 12
 $ : int [1:170] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 851 852 853 854 855 856 857 858 859 860 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 1021 1022 1023 1024 1025 1026 1027 1028 1029 1030 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 1191 1192 1193 1194 1195 1196 1197 1198 1199 1200 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 1361 1362 1363 1364 1365 1366 1367 1368 1369 1370 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 1531 1532 1533 1534 1535 1536 1537 1538 1539 1540 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 1701 1702 1703 1704 1705 1706 1707 1708 1709 1710 ...
 $ : int [1:170] 1871 1872 1873 1874 1875 1876 1877 1878 1879 1880 ...
```